# Meteor app hangs

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Working through [Discover Meteor](http://www.discovermeteor.com/) and just getting started is causing some headaches.

I ran the following:

```
mrt create microscope
mrt
```

Which gave me the output:

```
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[[[[[ ~/Projects/microscope ]]]]]

livedata: updating npm dependencies -- sockjs, websocket...
```

It just hangs, then eventually `localhost:3000` would return a "No data received" error. Any ideas?

Comment: What platform are you using? Do you have a reliable internet connection? If you try again does it do the same thing?

Comment: You're right - my connection was wonky. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a network connection problem - on subsequent runs the app runs fine.